# addClass Working But Not removeClass

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to create a toggling highlight effect using addClass and removeClass.

```
<head>
    <style>
        .box-highlight {
            border: 2px solid yellow;
        }
    </style>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="javascript/vendor/jquery-2.0.2.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $('#box').bind('click', function() {
                if ($(this).hasClass('box-highlight')) {
                    $(this).removeClass('box-highlight');
                }
                $(this).addClass('box-highlight');
            });
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="box" style="width: 100px; height: 100px; background-color: silver">

    </div>
</body>
```

The addClass is working properly, but removeClass does not. I know there is a toggleClass method but I am just wondering what is wrong with this code.

Comment: How do you know that `removeClass()` isn't working? You're removing the class and then immediately adding it again. So of course the element will still have the class when the function is done executing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're removing the class, then adding it back with no delay, before the UI can be redrawn. You need to do one *or* the other, which suggests an `else`:

```
if ($(this).hasClass('box-highlight')) {
  $(this).removeClass('box-highlight')
} else {
  $(this).addClass('box-highlight')
}
```

Comment: Yap, I forgot the else part. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The problem with your code is that it runs very quickly, and you won't see the effect :).
To make such effect, you can use a timer or delay. For example, you can do like this:

```
  $("#box").addClass("box-highlight")
      .delay(300).queue(function(next){
      $(this).removeClass("box-highlight");
      next();
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this................

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        $('#box').bind('click', function() {
            if ($(this).hasClass('box-highlight')) {
                $(this).removeClass('box-highlight');
            }else{
            $(this).addClass('box-highlight');
            }
        });
    });
```